# How to use native storage in place of localstorage?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic-native

```
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage/ngx';
export class AuthService {
  userData: any; // Save logged in user data
  constructor(
    public nativeStorage: NativeStorage,
    private platform :Platform,  
    public ngZone: NgZone // NgZone service to remove outside scope warning
  ) { }

  // Sign in with email/password
  // Returns true when user is logged in and email is verified
  
  get isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    const user = JSON.parse(this.nativeStorage.getItem('user'));
    return (user !== null && user.emailVerified !== false) ? true : false; 
  }
        
  // Sign in with Google
  // Auth logic to run auth providers
        
  // Returns true when user's email is verified
  get isEmailVerified(): boolean {
    const user = JSON.parse(nativeStorage.getItem('user'));
    return (user.emailVerified !== false) ? true : false;
  }
}
```

I was using previously localStorage and it was working fine, when I am using native storage is giving error *Cannot find name 'nativeStorage'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.nativeStorage'?*
and if I add replace it to this.nativeStorage
Error is *Argument of type 'Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.*

Comment: what is the error? do we guess?

Comment: Cannot find name 'nativeStorage'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.nativeStorage'?

Comment: so, the error is `cannot find nativeStorage`? that's odd ... your code doesn't have the word `nativeStorage` in it

Comment: i have imported import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage/ngx'; and in constructor private nativeStorage: NativeStorage

Comment: you know what helps someone debugging your code? the code that needs debugging ... please edit your question and add the code that needs debugging

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, always reference the Dependency injected variable by `this.`

Secondly, the return type of `this.nativeStorage.getItem('user')` is a `promise`. But the input type of `JSON.parse()` expects a `string`

So try the below code

```
async get isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    const savedUser = await this.nativeStorage.getItem('user');
    const user = savedUser ? JSON.parse(savedUser) : null;

    return (user !== null && user.emailVerified !== false) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: 'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.

Comment: async isLoggedIn() {
  const savedUser = await this.nativeStorage.getItem('user');
  const user = savedUser ? JSON.parse(savedUser) : null;

  return (user !== null && user.emailVerified !== false) ? true : false;
}  //This is working